# Переброс доступа к IP-адресу в локальную сеть

Tags: windows, http

У меня имеется некое устройство, подключенное к компьютеру, его настройки можно открыть по IP-адресу в браузере. Так вот, что мне требуется сделать, чтобы открыть эти настройки в браузере на другом компьютере подключенному локально к первому компьютеру, но не самому устройству (устройство и локальная сеть подключены к разным портам), Пробовал через netsh, но не получилось, возможно сделал что-то не так. Есть какие варианты?

Comment: Покажите сетевые настройки обеих сетевых карт и устройства (адрес-маска-шлюз-ДНС). Уточните ОС на компьютере, включая точную версию.

Comment: Windows 10 20H2 120.2212.3920.0

Comment: Какие именно настройки вас интересуют, ipv4?

Comment: Устройство - лидар подключенный к первому компьютеру, мне требуется открыть настройки этого лидара на другом компьютере, подключенном локально к первому

Comment: Подключайте устройство к локальной сети. Ну или мост между сетевыми адаптерами делайте.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы лидар работал на компьютере#1 подключенный к его сетевой плате, а на компьютере#2, подключенному к компьютеру#1 (другой сетевой плате), можно было открыть настройки этого лидара

Comment: Мост очень сильно тормозит трафик и будет слать весь трафик устройства на другой компьютер, мне нужно лишь иметь доступ к его настройкам по IP-адресу устройства

Comment: *"Мост очень сильно тормозит трафик и будет слать весь трафик устройства на другой компьютер"* - не надо выдумывать.

Comment: Включение моста простое решение, но мне нужно иметь соединение с этим компьютером, а мост это соединение убивает, хотя и дает возможность открыть настройки лидара

Comment: Соединение с компьютером убиваться не должно, только IP адрес у устройства будет другой.

Comment: И опять же проблема в том, что я подключаюсь к новому адресу компьютера и с него режется трафик, из-за этого плохо работает другой софт

Comment: Трафик был 180Мбит\с, и режется он до 5Мбит

Comment: пропробуйте [tor hidden service](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tor-hidden-services). Да, скорость медленная. Зато не надо заморачиваться с другими настройками. И эти настройки не будут мешать никаким другим софтам.

Comment: Так у вас оказывается проблема XY. На самом деле вам надо спрашивать, почему это режется трафик.